# How to generate a version 1 Guid in .NET?

Tags: .net, guid

As I understand it, Version 1 Guids that relied on timestamps and MAC address, were replaced by Version 4 - more random - in Windows 2000 or thereabouts.

What's the easiest way to generate a Version 1 guid from .Net, if I prefer it to a version 4?

(I *do* want the timestamp and (almost) unique machine id to be extractable.  I do control the entire environment - I'm ok with privacy/any loss of absolute randomness)

Thanks.

Comment: use a COMB from a version 2 GUID intead....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/rpcrt4/UuidCreateSequential.html) [`UuidCreateSequential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - it returns type 1 guids:

> For security reasons, `UuidCreate` was modified so that it no longer uses a machine's MAC address to generate UUIDs. `UuidCreateSequential` was introduced to allow creation of UUIDs using the MAC address of a machine's Ethernet card.